# Is the least-squares method used only to approximate lines? If yes why?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, least-squares, numerical-calculus

I have this exercise:

> Use the Normal Equations to determine the parabola $x^2+bx+c$ that
> best approximates $(-1,2),(1,-1),(2,1)$ using the least-squares
> method.

I already solved this. What is the question had been to approximate $ax^2+bx+c$ instead?

I tried to do the same thing, and I used these matrices:

$
\begin{cases} a - b + c = 2
\\ a + b + c = -1
\\4a + 2b + c = 1\end{cases}
 $

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
             1 & -1 & 1\\
             1 & 1 & 1 \\
             4 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \\
x = \begin{bmatrix}
             a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}\\
b = \begin{bmatrix}
             2 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I solved for $A^tAx = A^t b$ and got $(-1/3)x^2 + 2.3333333$. I tried this on [this website](https://goodcalculators.com/quadratic-regression-calculator/) and got these results
[image]

I assume a different and more precise method was used. Can someone explain to me why the least-squares method isn't so good for polynomials of degree >1 (assuming I did this right)?

---

Nevermind this, I made a mistake on b. I could get the same result as the website when I fixed it. Closing.

Comment: You found the only parabola which passes through the given points. The value of the coefficient $a$ is not $1.$  However, the least squares method required to find a parabola with the first coefficient $a=1.$

Comment: Your fit, $F(x)=-\frac 13x^2+\frac 73$ is terrible.  $F(-1)=2$ as it should be but $F(1)$ is also $2$ which is very far off.  $F(2)=1$ as it should.  Clearly your polynomial does not minimize least squares (there is a quadratic which fits exactly, as the graph shows.  Something must have gone wrong with your calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I solved for $A^tAx=A^tx$"? Where does $b$ come in? You have the equation $Ax=b$ and are trying to solve for $x$, so $x=A^{-1}b$ is a natural approach.

Comment: @Karl I meant to say $A^tb$ instead of $A^tx$ sorry. I solved it by doing $x = (A^tA)^{-1}A^tb$

Comment: $b$ should be $[2, -1,  1]'$?

Comment: @user46666 Yes! I forgot to change that from the last exercise. I will fix my OP